# Rails "redirect_to" Nested routes with latest model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have two models nested, 
Gameround > currentplayer

Gameround is shown on play.html.erb, I also make the currentplayers there. When the currentplayer is made I want to redirect the user to currentplayer#show but I can't seem to figure out the way to route the link. I've tried everything I can think of.

**So I need a link that says:**

Get url to thiscurrentGameround/ThiscurrentplayerIjustmade

My controller:

```
def createPlayerforUser

        @latest_game_round = Gameround.order(created_at: :desc).first
        @currentplayer = @latest_game_round.currentplayers.create({
            log_id: @current_user.id
        });

        if @currentplayer.save

            redirect_to  url_for([@gameround, @currentplayer])
        end

    end
```

config.routes

```
 resources :gamerounds do 
    resources :currentplayers
  end 
  resources :gamesessions
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

 # Artikkel, Alien liste
  resources :expansions do
    resources :aliens
  end

  resources :users

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  #root 'gamesessions#play'
  root 'gamesessions#new'
  #root 'application#show'
  #root 'public#index'
  get "signup", :to => "users#new"
  get "login", :to => "sessions#login"
  post "login_attempt", :to => "sessions#login_attempt"
  get "logout", :to => "sessions#logout"
  get "profile", :to => "sessions#profile"
  get "setting", :to => "sessions#setting"
  get "play", :to => "gamesessions#play"
  get "wait", :to => "gamesessions#wait"
  get "aliens", :to => "aliens#index"
```

Comment: Type `$ rake routes` in the terminal. You can see there the names of the routes. In this case it will be `redirect_to gamearound_currentplayer_path(@gamearound, @currentplayer)`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :) but I've tried that and it does not work for some reason. I've posted the error message in the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run rake routes in the terminal, your list of routes should include one for showing currentplayer. You should be able to use

```
redirect_to gameround_currentplayer_url(@latest_game_round, @current_player)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've looked at the routes and tried that but it gives me this error message:

NoMethodError in GamesessionsController#play
 undefined method `gameround_currentplayer' for #<GamesessionsController:0x007f8a7a3e8558>

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer, which I've corrected.

Comment: Thanks! I still had to find the currentplayer id, so I did this. And now it works perfectly! Thank you for all your help! +1 
`
@currentPid = @latest_game_round.currentplayers.find_by(log_id: @current_user.id )

   redirect_to  gameround_currentplayer_url(@latest_game_round, @currentPid)`

Comment: Nice! Glad I was able to help.